# Given IEEE binary representation of a real how to get its true binary representation in Java?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

I am just wonder how to use bit operations to achieve the goal: given an IEEE binary representation of a real, for example, `40AC0000` (5.375 in decimal), how to get its true binary representation (expecting `101.011` for the example) in Java?

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of a tough question, especially if you don't already know about IEEE floats.

Since there are 4 bytes in your number, it's single precision. This means it has a structure of 1 sign bit, 8 Exponent bits and 23 Mantissa bits. The sign bit is obvious. The meaning of the exponent bits affects how you interpret the Mantissa bits. First check the 8 exponents bits. If they are all 0, you have a denormalized number; if they are all 1, you have an infinity value or a NaN; otherwise, it is normalized.

In the normalized , take the exponent bits, interpret it as an 8 bit number and subtract 127_10 (or 0xf7) from it. This is your exponent. Then take the remaining Mantissa bits, add a leading 1. Your result is then (-1)^[Sign] * 1.[Mantissa] * 2^[Exponent].

If it is a denormalized number, your exponent is -126 (1-127). In this case, interpret as (-1)^[Sign] * 0.[Mantissa] * 2^[Exponent].

In the remaining cases, if the Mantissa is all 0s, your number is (-1)^[Sign] * infinity. Otherwise, your float is a NaN.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, I understand IEEE representation of floats and doubles. Do you mind writing out a working java code for this? Ideally I would like to explicitly use bit operations to achieve this. Many thanks.

Comment: If you understand the concepts it should be straightforward. Use bit maps such as (num & 0x80000000) for sign, (num & 0x78000000) for exponent, and (num & 0x007fffff) for mantissa. You really ought to be able to figure it out from there. Just shift everything where you need it and multiply to get the right answer.

I don't have time to write all of the code for you.

Comment: Last tip: you should use the exponent to figure out to where you should move your binary point.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean Float.floatToIntBits() and Float.intBitsToFloat() ?

Comment: the IEEE is in base 2.  These methods don't convert the number it only makes the bits used available as an `int` (It has some special handling for NaNs as Java assumes there is only one NaN but IEEE supports many such values)

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "true binary representation"? There is nothing "untrue" about the hex representation (40AC0000).

You can convert between different radixes (hex, binary, decimal) using the methods on Integer:

```
Float.floatToIntBits(new Float("5.375"));
// = 1085014016

Integer.toString(1085014016, 16);
// = "40ac0000"

Integer.valueOf("40AC0000", 16);
// = 1085014016

Integer.toString(1085014016, 2); 
// returns 1000000101011000000000000000000
```

Comment: I used "true binary representation" to mean the genuine/unmanipulated format `101.011`. I do not see this in any of your printout. Thanks!